# Passing email address in custom token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-console, firebase-admin

I have simple backend that can register users and generate jwt's using the firebase-admin package.

When I login with this custom token in firebase console -> authentication the email address is not set. Is there a way to be able to see the email address from there?

Comment: can you show your new approach ? I really need it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`updateUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#updateUser) method to update the user's email address (detailed docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user)):

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  email: "modifiedUser@example.com"
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error updating user:", error);
  });
```

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but I didn't test it since I'm trying a new approach now

Comment: Hey @stulleman, I'm having the same issue as you and about to use jwngr's solution, but curious; what was your new approach?